# How to update boot loader in IOIO-OTG board

Tags: java, android, ioio

I am working on an android app. I want to update boot loader in IOIO-OTG board . So how to update boot loader?..So what is the procedure to update??

Answer (score 0):

following the complete procedure to upgrade the APP inside IOIO board , but you can't upgrade the BOOTLOADER without External programer or another IOIO board .

https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki/IOIO-OTG-Bootloader-and-IOIODude

Comment: Please try to explain Whats in the link? That may be needed for future reference if the link content is changed or deleted.

Answer (score -1):

First of all, the bootloader it's protected to write. To update the bootloader you will need another IOIO-OTG board or a PIC programer like an PICkit, and wire to the corrects pins (See datasheet of PIC24F). See [this link](https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki/The-IOIO-Manager-Application#the-programmer-screen) how it's made.

It seems to be more easy with another IOIO-OTG board. You just have to install. on android device, the "Programmer" from the application library and run the app according the instructions.
NOTE: you will have to power supply  both boards for update the bootloader.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Thanks @Neeku.
I improved the answer.